# copy a publishing - could this break a site collection

Tags: publishing-page

Say, I do following, could it break the site collection?

1. I download a publishing page "SourcePage.aspx" from pages library to my computer
2. I rename the publishing page "DuplicatePage.aspx"
3. I upload the "DuplicatePage.aspx" back to same "Pages" library
4. Edit the "DuplicatePage.aspx"
5. Try to publish "DuplicatePage.aspx"

Could this break the whole site collection? I could see the site in mobile mode, or I can hit it with powershell or I can see everything via SP Designer. However, I get a /Server error through browser. Nothing would fix this (like setting up the masterpage to v4.master or night.master or minimum.master).

Answer (score 0):

Is this edited page your home page?  If so then it may be just the page that is a problem?  Can you get to /_layouts/settings.aspx?  If so then try creating a new page and make that the home page.